# Responde a usuario redireccionado. Protocolo OAuth2

Tags: c#, .net, oauth2

En el protocolo OAuth2, una vez que el usuario ha concedido permisos a una aplicación (Windows Forms) y es redireccionado a la url https://www.youawesomeapp.com/?code=SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE, ¿cómo se puede obtener el código SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE en un desarrollo realizado en c#?

El funcionamiento de la aplicación estaría explicado en https://bantotal.github.io/bdevelopers-doc/#obtener-el-access-token

El método CallInitialUri realiza una llamada a la url UriBTDevelopers. Después de la llamada, se recibe una pantalla de login, que se muestra en el webBrowser1; Desde el browser,el usuario se loguea y se le solicita que conceda permisos a mi aplicación.

Si el usuario concede los permisos necesarios, la aplicación tiene que recibir el código en la url: [https://www.miaplicación.com/?code=SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE](https://www.miaplicaci%C3%B3n.com/?code=SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE). Es en este punto donde tengo dudas... ¿Cómo se realiza la "escucha" a esa url después de que el usuario conceda los permisos necesarios?

```
public async Task CallInitialUri ( )
{
    String              strUriApp;                  // Cadena Uri de la aplicación.
    String              strUriBTDevelopers;     // Cadena Uri de autorización.
    String              strClientId;                // ClientId;
    HttpClient          pClient;                        // Cliente HTTP.

    try
    {
        /* Se inicializan las variablas necesarias */
        strClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        strUriApp = "https://miaplicacion.com/";
        pClient = new HttpClient();
        pClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        pClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        /* Se crea la cadena Uri */
        strUriBTDevelopers = "https://developers.bantotal.com/auth/dialog/authorize?client_id=" + strClientId +"&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + strUriApp;

        /* Se navega al Uri de forma asíncrona */
        Task<String> stringTask = pClient.GetStringAsync(strUriBTDevelopers);

        /* Se muestra la web en el navegador de la aplicación */
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = await stringTask;
    }
    catch ( Exception Ex )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Has intentado algo? Cuelga el código para ver por donde estas tirando :)

Comment: Bienvenido Sergio, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

al finalizar la autentificación, llama a la url que le pasastes cuando finalice, en ese momento, envía por parámetros el SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE en los parametros del request de la llamada que realiza al finalizar.

Si puedes indicar algo de código de la página https://www.youawesomeapp.com/?code=SERVER_GENERATED_AUTHORIZATION_CODE, como recoges esta llamada, que esta url...